# Why are objects which are stationary with respect to the camera motion-blurred?

Tags: motion-blur

Why is everything blurred?

My camera is a child of the vehicle illustrated below, and is travelling at the same speed, so why is there so much motion blur on the whole vehicle, instead of just the wheels? I am very confused about this motion blur business.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information
is visible in this page, instead of asking users to visit links just
to understand your question. Please use the [edit]link at the bottom 
of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the 
tools on the site to upload images directly. See:
[How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: Maybe lower the motion blur to see what's happening?

Comment: thanks #emir i'll do that. i was very confused.